# How to change Parse filename on download?

Tags: php, jquery, file, parse-platform, filenames

I'm using this code to download files from Parse

```
query.find().then(function(results) {
    window.open(results[0].attributes.File.url(), "_self");
});
```

and then i get a file name like this :

```
tfss-de626baf-ab29-4aaf-9bce-6b5876862a75-myfile.zip
```

Is it possible to change the file name on download to this?

```
myfile.zip
```

If there is any method using HTML5 a tag or jQuery or JavaScript or PHP that would be great.

Comment: You can try the download attribute on an anchor tag

Comment: i already tired download attribute but no luck ! maybe i did it wrong, can you write me a working method for parse sample in here using download attribute ?

Comment: Regarding [our discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621075/how-to-install-wp-smart-pagination-step-by-step), I am not looking for paid work. I am making a request, on behalf of our community, that question authors do not add pleading messages for the purpose of coercing readers into providing more volunteer work than they have time or capacity for. The canonical discussion [is here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569).

Answer (score 0):

You can server side by setting the `Content-Disposition` header. However, depending how you are serving it, you may not have access to change it.

For [browsers that support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) it the `a` tag has a `download` attribute that would allow you to change the file name.

Comment: actually i dont know how to use Content-Disposition header and i dont know what is the correct and working method to work with parse.com, if you can write me a working method with download attribute that would be really great.

Comment: Where is the file coming from? If its being generated with server side code, you can generally control headers. If its being distributed from another system you may not be able to. AWS S3 does allow you to set most headers on objects.

Comment: the file comes from parse server and a complete links looks like : http://files.parsetfss.com/72e2aa80-b2e7-4aed-956c-d53bdd05b76c/tfss-de626baf-ab29-4aaf-9bce-6b5876862a75-myfile.zip

Comment: You probably wont be able to use the content-disposition option.  The download attribute wont work in all browsers. But you can give Dev user's answer a try.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like:

```
query.find().then(function(results) {
    saveContent(results[0].attributes.File.url(), "myfile.zip");
    // or results[0].attr('download','myfile.zip');
});

function saveContent(fileContents, fileName)
{
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = fileName;
    link.href = 'data:,' + fileContents;
    link.click();
}
```

Comment: i just tried your method file will download and save with the name but the size of the file is just 1 KB instead of 867 KB !! do you have any idea ? it would be great if you can fix this :)

Comment: No one can help me with this problem ?